# Does a sparsified correlation matrix follow the Perron Frobenius theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, sparse-matrices

Consider an N x N correlation matrix which has been sparsified to retain only the sqrt(N)*N highest elements.

It has the following characteristics:
- Sparse
- Non-negative (values are positive real numbers in [0; 1])
- Symmetrical
- The diagonal is equal 1
- W elements are strongly connected. The remaining (N-W) elements have null vectors (the columns and rows at these entries are composed only of zeros, except the diagonal value).

An example matrix:

```
 1 1 0 0 0;  
 1 1 1 0 0;  
 0 1 1 1 0;  
 0 0 1 1 0;  
 0 0 0 0 1
```

*W = 4 connected elements. Note how element 5 only has zeros in its columns and rows.*

To give some context behind this question: During eigendecomposition of the N x N matrix: the **eigenvector associated to the highest eigenvalue** has only positive values (and is sometimes almost **constant**).

I am trying to find a reason for this oddity.

Is the N x N matrix considered to be irreducible? Does it follow the Perron Frobenius theorem?

If not, what other theorem is likely to explain the oddities observed with the eigenvector?

Answer (score 0):

Up to a permutation similarity, your matrix has the form
$$
M = \pmatrix{A&0\\0&I_{N-W}}
$$
where $A$ is the $W \times W$ submatrix corresponding to your strongly connected elements.  Notably, $A$ is irreducible because it describes a strongly connected network, so the Perron-Frobenius theorem applies.

If $x$ (a column-vector) is the Perron eigenvector of $A$ and $\lambda$ the corresponding eigenvalue, then we will also have
$$
M \pmatrix{x\\0} = \lambda \pmatrix{x\\0}
$$
where I have used $\tilde x = (x,0)$ to indicate that we have added $0$s to the end of the vector $x$ to make it a vector in $\Bbb R^n$.

As long as the largest eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ is greater than $1$, $\tilde x$ will be the unique eigenvector of $M$ corresponding to $\lambda$, which is also the largest eigenvalue of $M$.  To see that this is the case, it suffices to note that the eigenvectors of a block matrix $\pmatrix{A&0\\0&B}$ will necessarily have the form $(x,y)$ where $Ax = \mu x$ and $By = \mu y$ for some value $\mu$.

As for the eigenvector being nearly constant: note that a stochastic matrix (a matrix with constant row-sums) will have a constant eigenvector. By the continuous dependence of eigenvalues/eigenvectors on matrix entries, if the row-sums of $A$ are close to being identical, then the maximal eigenvector of $A$ will be close to the constant eigenvector.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this clears up a bunch regarding the Perron Frobenius. The N x N matrix sadly doesn't have constant row-sums (row sums differ quite a bit, and patterns for these variations are visible in subsequent eigenvectors). For the case of W = 0; The largest eigenvector is almost constant, and close to nil (its elements vary between 0.01 and 0.1). Unsure if this is due to it being the Perron eigenvector, or if there are other properties at play here. What do you think?

Comment: @poultrynews for the $W=0$ case, do you simply mean that the matrix is an identity matrix? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @poultrynews My hunch is that strange things when the largest eigenvalue is $1$, merely as a consequence of the algorithm you're using.  Otherwise, there will be a positive eigenvalue larger than $1$ with a one-dimensional eigenspace.

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant to write W = N, meaning that all elements of the matrix are strongly connected (with no 0 vectors). The largest eigenvalue is always larger than 1; it sometimes surpasses 2. It is substantially higher than the second eigenvalue. What I meant to say previously is that the largest eigenvector's elements are close to nil. All the elements of that eigenvector have the same sign, and have a very low variance; despite being associated to the largest eigenvalue (which is > 2 sometimes).